# Do Javascript functions need parenthesis when you call them?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I'm watching a video tutorial on AJAX and the guy writes something and calls it a function, but he isn't calling it.

I am slightly confused, here is a picture of what he is doing:
[image]

Don't you need to have ()?

Comment: Yes of course, but this thing takes you on stackoverflow!

Comment: You could have copy/pasted the code, instead of the picture :)

Comment: it was from a video :P

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need parenthesis to execute a function.

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
```

doesn't execute `handleServerResponse`, just assign it to `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange`.

Answer (score 2):

That is assigning a function pointer (bit loose with terminology there?). The function `onreadystatechange` on `xmlHttp` will now point at the function `handleServerResponse`. Putting `()` would have executed the `handleServerResponse` function, and assigned the return value to `onreadystatechange`.

Answer (score 0):

You either use parentheses or not depending upon what you want to do.

If you want to pass a reference to a function so that function can be called by some other code at a later time, then you do NOT use parentheses.  That is what is happening in your particular code example and is the correct and only way to pass a reference to a function that is NOT executed now, but can be executed later.

This:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
```

is simply assigning a reference to the `handlerServerResponse` function so that the function can be called in the future when the ajax call is actually done.  This is the correct way to do it for this particular use.

---

If you want to execute a function NOW rather than just assign a reference to it, then you must use parentheses.

If you did:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse();
```

then, it would execute the function `handlerServerResponse()` NOW and assign the return value from the function to `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange` which is not what you want in this case.